# How can I find out when an HTML element becomes read-only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a web page with a form using Bootstrap 5. One of the controls on the form is a select box, and I just noticed that it keeps having a gray background. At first, I thought it was just my browser's autocomplete, but upon further investigation, I discovered that select form-control had somehow been assigned read-only.

HTML:

```
<select name="country" class="form-control " id="country">
    ...
</select>
```

CSS, from the Dev Tools highlighting the control:

```
.form-control:disabled, .form-control:read-only {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

In Dev Tools, `.form-control:read-only` is highlighted, so that means that it is active. I cannot see anywhere in the HTML that my select has been marked as read-only, and I can't figure out how to find out when that is happening. There's no way that it is marked as read-only on the first render. I can't find anything in my JavaScript that could be changing the state to read-only. I do have JavaScript that populates the select with a value, but when I comment that out, the form-control is still marked as read-only.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out why my select control is marked as read-only, and what to do to prevent that.

Comment: It's `readonly`, not `read-only`, right?

Comment: I had to double-check myself, @ZoliSzabó, but it is actually `read-only`.

Comment: You might be using some strange bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/a44f3f47cbd87484e8227ab358236dae7a6bc4e1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L2194

Comment: That did it--if you give your response as an answer, I'll accept it. I was using 5.0.0, and the most recent version was 5.0.1. I did a quick swap and everything worked fine.

Comment: I am not sure it works-works, because it might be just that there is no CSS rule to apply anymore for your `read-only` control. You real problem (i.e. why `read-only` is applied automatically?) isn't necessarily resolved. Or is it?

Comment: It is resolved. The ":read-only" rule no longer shows up as being applied to the select element. I have no idea what could have caused this. Perhaps it was just a cache invalidation error?

Comment: That's because there is no `:read-only` rule anymore in Bootstrap v5.0.1. But is the attribute still there in the DOM?

Comment: That's the thing. It was never in the DOM. I could never figure out how it was being applied to it. Based on MutationObserver, it doesn't seem to have ever been added later on. Although, more research seems to indicate perhaps an issue with TinyMCE, but I never used that on this web page. It's all still an enigma at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe changes in the DOM tree (attributes included). See the linked page for example usage.